# How can i see the blob-name when downloading from Azure storage acct?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a blob in azure storage account and am using the following to try to download :

```
 az storage blob download --account-name <storage-account-name> --account-key <storage-account-key> --container-name <container-name> --name <blob-name> --file <local-file-path>
```

The issue is what is the , where can i get that from ?

Is this the correct way to download from storage account ?

Comment: Blob name is your `file name` which you stored in azure blob storage.

Comment: You can use the command `az storage blob list` to list the names of blobs that you stored in Azure blob storage  refer to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-list

Comment: To download i use:        az storage blob download --account-name <storage-account-name> --account-key <storage-account-key> --container-name <container-name> --name <blob-name> --file <local-file-path>. But i get something in the powershell window as follows:    az storage blob download --account-name 'testaccount' --acco .    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError.                                                                                                      The file downloads. Can i just ignore this ?

Comment: Yep, you can ignore this.

Comment: ok if i ignore ... cause i run it from a ci/cd pipeline and it may not return as a success

Comment: Check the below commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this the correct way to download from a storage account?

If you need to download a particular file, your command is correct.

> How can I see the blob-name when downloading from an Azure storage account?

First, list your files from Azure blob storage using the command below.

**Command:**

```
az storage blob list --account-name "<Your-storage account -name>" --container-name "<Your -container name>" --account-key "<Your-key>" --query "[].name" --output tsv
```

**Output:**

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> az storage blob list --account-name "venkat789" --container-name "demo" --account-key "xxx" --query "[].name" --output tsv
sample html file download.html
sample.png
```

[image]

The above command lists the names of all blobs in the **`demo`** container of the **`venkat789`** storage account, using the specified account key for authentication. The output shows two blob names: "sample html file download.html" and "sample.png".

Now, if you need to download a particular blob like sample.png, you can use the same command.

**Command and Output:**

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> az storage blob download --account-name "venkat789" --container-name "demo" --account-key "xxxx" --name "sample.png" --file "C:\Users\xxxxx\example.png"
Alive[################################################################]  100.0000%
Finished[#############################################################]  100.0000%
{
  "container": "demo",
  "content": "",
  "contentMd5": null,
  "deleted": false,
  "encryptedMetadata": null,
  "encryptionKeySha256": null,
  "encryptionScope": null,
  "hasLegalHold": null,
  "hasVersionsOnly": null,
  "immutabilityPolicy": {
    "expiryTime": null,
    "policyMode": null
  },
  "isAppendBlobSealed": null,
  "isCurrentVersion": true,
  "lastAccessedOn": null,
  "metadata": {},
  "name": "sample.png",
  "objectReplicationDestinationPolicy": null,
  "objectReplicationSourceProperties": [],
  "properties": {
    "appendBlobCommittedBlockCount": null,
    "blobTier": null,
    "blobTierChangeTime": null,
    "blobTierInferred": null,
    "blobType": "BlockBlob",
    "contentLength": 18063,
    "contentRange": "bytes None-None/18063",
    "contentSettings": {
      "cacheControl": null,
      "contentDisposition": null,
      "contentEncoding": null,
      "contentLanguage": null,
      "contentMd5": "xxxxx",
      "contentType": "image/png"
    },
    "copy": {
      "completionTime": null,
      "destinationSnapshot": null,
      "id": null,
      "incrementalCopy": null,
      "progress": null,
      "source": null,
      "status": null,
      "statusDescription": null
    },
    "creationTime": "2024-01-16T05:25:53+00:00",
    "deletedTime": null,
    "etag": "xxxx"",
    "lastModified": "2024-01-16T05:25:53+00:00",
    "lease": {
      "duration": null,
      "state": "available",
      "status": "unlocked"
    },
    "pageBlobSequenceNumber": null,
    "pageRanges": null,
    "rehydrationStatus": null,
    "remainingRetentionDays": null,
    "serverEncrypted": true
  },
  "rehydratePriority": null,
  "requestServerEncrypted": true,
  "snapshot": null,
  "tagCount": null,
  "tags": null,
  "versionId": "20xxxx69385Z"
}
```

The downloaded file is saved to the specified local file path, and the output shows the properties of the downloaded blob.

If you need to download more number of files, you can use the `az storage blob download-batch` command.

**Reference:**

- For single file: [az storage blob | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-download)
- For multiple files: [az storage blob | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-download-batch)

Comment: yep this way gives the same error as described above that i can ignore

Comment: Use this command: `az storage blob download --account-name "xxx" --container-name "xxx" --account-key "sxxxx" --name "sample.png" --file "C:\Usersxxxxexample1.png" 2>$null` it will ignore error message and it will download your file.

Comment: End of the line just add `2>$null` in your command which indicates error message to null, effectively suppressing it, and tell me if you have further more queries.

Comment: Hope this addressed your comments.

Comment: Glad to know that it worked.